# How to change the language when working with the a0poster class?

Tags: languages, posters

How can I change the language (i.e. the `and` in the author separations) of the `a0poster` class?

For example: `\documentclass[german]{a0poster}` did not work, it still shows the `and` in English.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Using `babel` with german option does not do the trick?

Comment: Are there any news here? Did you resolve the issue? Can you make up a self answer by now?